# PHP & Javascript Date Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to print out an array of dates pulled from an API, which come out formatted as YYYYmmdd, i.e. 20160701. When I convert them to a friendlier format and then go to print them in Highcharts, it actually will do a mathematical calculation based on the operator being used to separate the date elements. Obviously that's not what I want it to do. So the first date is actually performing 7 minus 1 minus 2016, resulting in the -2010. Does anyone know what is causing this?

**PHP Snippet**

```
foreach ($arr['rows'] as $item){
 $dates[] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $item[0])->format('m-d- Y');
 }
```

**Javascript Highchart Plugin**

```
$('#myChart').highcharts({
          xAxis: {
              categories: [
                <?php
                echo implode(',', $dates);
                ?>
              ]
          },
```

**What the dates end up looking like:**

[image: Output Image]

Comment: could it be the extra space in your `format` call? `format('m-d- Y');` should be `format('m-d-Y');`, right?

Comment: Why not just use a **datetime** x axis type, and skip this hassle anyway?

Comment: If you are going to do it this way, though, use php's **json_encode()** function rather than implode(), ie: *xAxis: { categories: <?php echo json_encode($dates); ?> }*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not injecting any quotes in the Javascript source.

What you get is something like:

```
$('#myChart').highcharts({
      xAxis: {
          categories: [ 7-1-2016 ]   //  <--- should be [ "7-1-2016" ]
      }
});
```

which is evaluated as `categories: [ -2010 ]` on the *Javascript side*.

You should do:

```
$('#myChart').highcharts({
      xAxis: {
          categories: [
            <?php
              echo '"'.implode('","', $dates).'"';
            ?>
          ]
      }
});
```

Or if you prefer to have this fixed in the PHP code that is building this array:

```
foreach ($arr['rows'] as $item){
    $dates[] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $item[0])->format('"m-d-Y"');
}
```

**EDIT**: as suggested by jlbriggs, a better approach would be to use `json_encode()`.

At least on `$dates` ...

```
$('#myChart').highcharts({
      xAxis: {
          categories: <?php echo json_encode($dates); ?>
      }
});
```

... or on the whole object passed to `highcharts()` (assuming it's entirely built on the PHP side):

```
$('#myChart').highcharts(<?php echo json_encode($highChartsObject); ?>);
```

Comment: While that works, it's basically the (open-to-error) long-way-around to accomplish what **json_encode()** does for you explicitly.

Comment: @jlbriggs - Yes. I focused on the _'why is it not working as expected'_ explanation, but you're of course perfectly right. Answer edited accordingly.